# Is it possible to control data of another server using cpanel

Tags: php, ubuntu, cpanel

We have around 4 servers each of them having multiple websites hosted in them.

We want to update all the websites of all those servers using cpanel. For that, should we install cpanel in all the 4 servers or can we control all 4 servers from single cpanel instance ? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 0):

Just install cpanel in one server and after changing value in `config.inc.php` which is inside phpMyAdmin folder, you are able to handle database from all 4 servers.

This file will have content like this,

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
```

Change `user`, `password` and `host` to connect